# Memory leak caused by WPF view containing a WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, memory-leaks, unmanaged

I'm working on an MVVM (WPF) application that features one main container. The view that is displayed depends on a menu item that is selected (*e.g.* Home, Product Information etc.). Whenever a view is accessed for the first time, memory consumption goes up slightly as the associated view model is instantiated; when the same view is further accessed, memory stays the same since the existing instance of the associated view model is used.

However, one view containing a `WebBrowser` control increases memory usage by ~80MB each time it is accessed without exception; this memory never gets freed — repeatedly switching between Home and that view can cause the application to run out of memory and crash. Using a memory profiler I discovered that this increase happens in unmanaged code, particularly `user32.dll`.

Going through other StackOverflow posts, I noticed that there is a recurring problem with `WebBrowser` and memory leaking, but most posts point towards this being an issue with IE7. We're enforcing the usage of IE11 for our application. I need some help investigating this problem and a potential resolution. I'm afraid I can't post code, but any hint can be helpful.

Comment: Internet Explorer typically has a lot of issues in general. I would recommend not limiting your program to IE and branch it out to support other , better maintained, browsers.

Comment: @Symon this is actually the plan for a future release, to switch to [CefSharp](https://cefsharp.github.io/). I was only wondering if we could find a hotfix until then. In my opinion, for this feature the best solution is just open the link in the browser, but I don't make those decisions.

Comment: Then the next step would be dropping a breakpoint where you suspect the memory leak is taking place (sounds like you have a good idea where it is). Then, double check to make sure everything is being disposed as needed and that instances needed to be rid of *are* being rid of.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and it has nothing to do with the `WebBrowser` control being leaky. The code (I didn't write it) passed the instance of `WebBrowser` from the view to the view model thus making the view model contain a hard reference to the view. Since the lifespan of the view model corresponds to the lifespan of the application, those references to the views were forever held. Replacing that logic with a proper one fixed the issue.